# HTML and CSS image alignment

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

Why do my html header search icon and home icon not align with the rest of the header when zoomed in or out past 100%?

[image]

CSS

```
.search {
  background-color: #333;
  float: right;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8.5px 16px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: You've described two icons, written the CSS for one of them (I think?), and neglected to offer an HTML, or the images themselves. Are they siblings? Are they the same size? What (relevant) styles are applied to, or by, the parent element? Please understand, we *want* to help you, but without relevant information all we can possibly  do is guess based on our own experiences of situations that are likely vastly different to your own. Add the relevant "*[mcve]*" code - HTMl and CSS - to your question, and then we may be able to offer something useful. Also, look at the "*[ask]*" guidance.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding display:inline-block and height:100% to the image container.

Comment: Added to the css, but does not seem to help.

Comment: I've seen images do this if the actual HTML itself is on two different lines in the code. If that's the case, try putting the code on the same line in the code editor.